# mosfet substitute

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design

I have a design that requires a certain mosfet. The design is [here](https://easyeda.com/example/Uberclamp_Schematic_PCB_and_BoM-r4YgysK2k). This is the schematic [image: schematic]

I can't find a supplier in Canada that has the Mosfets, m1/m2.  It calls for a DMP4015SK3-13. Digikey has a 20 week lead time. Is it possible to substitute another mosfet?

The one it calls for is [here](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/DMP4015SK3-13/DMP4015SK3-13DICT-ND/2792434).
Can I use [this](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/FDD4141/FDD4141CT-ND/1678982) as a substitute?

Comment: Post the schematic, not a link. State to which component designator you are referring to.

Comment: added the schematic.

Comment: Have you tried Electrosonic or Active Components?

Comment: yes I did. As well as mouser and newark.

Comment: The specified MOSFET has a higher rated current and VgsMax than the substitute that you are proposing, but not by a significant margin. If you can ensure that the FET will be operated within these slightly narrower limiting ratings you should be fine, at least for operating in the ohmic mode.

Comment: Looks very non-critical. I would go for anything with same or higher voltage rating, same or lower RdsON and similar Vgsth and call it a day.

Comment: the supply voltage is 5vdc, and the max current it would ever see would be 1A. So I would think my proposed replacement would be fine.